# Access widget stop processing

Tags: sitefinity

I have three widgets on a page one widget checks the access to page and I wanted the other widget's not to process if the access widget returns false. Is there anyway I can do that? Almost need something like `stopPropagation`. The access widget returns a just a div when access is true but when access is false it will return a restriction message.

Comment: They can't communicate unless you use like session variables... But even then you couldn't control the order in which they execute.

Comment: So what would be the best thing to do?

Comment: @veselin-vasilev any idea on this one ?

Comment: Is there any Conditional Logic I can include in the widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That access-checker widget should redirect to a Login page or something (e.g. throw a 403 unauthorized exception) if the user does not have access.

Alternatively you can set something in TempData, e.g.

```
TempData["UserRestricted"] = true;
```

and then read that value in the other widgets and act appropriately, but this makes them a bit tight-coupled.

You can also combine these widgets into one?

Comment: Thanks @veselin-vasilev if I do the redirect what happens to the other widgets.

Comment: If the page redirects to another page - then it depends what's on that other page.